# Looping through days in month in year as json

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm trying to make an endpoint for a calendar that will be used to add events against.

I want to try and use `json` and build it up to then parse into a calendar view.

Then try and add events by merging the `json` data as seen here:

- https://phppot.com/php/php-json-array-merge/

At this point, I'm struggling to get the other data into the endpoint. This is what I have so far:

```php
// build variables
$getStart = '2020-01-01'; // come from $_GET

$monthStartDate = new DateTime( $getStart );
$monthFinishDate = clone $monthStartDate;
$monthFinishDate->modify('last day of december');
$monthInterval = new DateInterval( 'P1M' );

// set the variables
$monthRange = new DatePeriod(
                $monthStartDate,
                $monthInterval,
                $monthFinishDate
            );

// loop the months
foreach ($monthRange as $month) {

    // loop the days
    $dayStartDate = new DateTime( $month->format('M') );
    $dayFinishDate = clone $dayStartDate;
    $dayFinishDate->modify('next month');
    $dayInterval = new DateInterval( 'P1D' );

    $dayRange = new DatePeriod(
                    $dayStartDate,
                    $dayInterval,
                    $dayFinishDate
    );

    // build the calendar json
    $calendar[] = [ $month->format('m') => [
                        'year'  => $month->format('Y'),
                        'month' => $month->format('F'),
                        'days' => [

                            // error here because loop in $array
                            foreach( $dayRange as $day ) {
                                $day->format('d') => [
                                    'dayOfWeek' => $day->format('l'),
                                    'events' => []
                                ],
                            }
                        ],
                    ]];
}

// print it
echo json_encode($calendar);
```

I'm fairly sure its because the loop inside the arrow, but I cant think of any other way to get the days in that month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to build the days array first, so the foreach will create a days array and then add the completed array to the calendar...

```
$days = [];
foreach( $dayRange as $day ) {
    $days[$day->format('d')] = [
            'dayOfWeek' => $day->format('l'),
            'events' => []
    ];
}
$calendar[] = [ $month->format('m') => [
        'year'  => $month->format('Y'),
        'month' => $month->format('F'),
        'days' => $days
        ]
        
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can't use the foreach inside an array. Here you could use a function to do so:

```php
function dayRangeLoop($dayRange) {
    $result = [];
    foreach( $dayRange as $day ) {
        $result[$day->format('d')] = [
            'dayOfWeek' => $day->format('l'),
            'events' => []
        ];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

and then call it in yourcalendar build:

```php
// build the calendar json
$calendar[] = [ $month->format('m') => [
    'year'  => $month->format('Y'),
    'month' => $month->format('F'),
    'days' => dayRangeLoop($dayRange)
]];
```